# Cast to an array of Message

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, classcastexception, toarray

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I have a "simple" question.

I have an ArrayList , but when i transform this ArrayList to array using the method toArray from the ArrayList object and cast it to Message[] it throws an java.lang.ClassCastException ? The Message class belongs to package "javax.mail.Message"
Snippet of code :

```
 List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    --code to fullfill the List
   (Message[]) messageList.toArray();
```

Throws and exception: 
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljavax.mail.Message;***

Can anyone explain me why this happen ?

With the best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an array of `Message` and then pass it to the toArray(). The method [you are calling](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) does return an array of `Object`, hence the classcast exception. You cannot cast an array of one object type to an array of another, even if the second object extends the first.

```
Message[] messages = new Message[messageList.size()];
messageList.toArray(messages);
```

Check the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

Although an `Object` may be casted to `Message` (sometimes) you cannot cast an array of Objects to array of Messages even if all the objects are Messages, as in your case.

This is similar (but not the same) to the fact that you cannot cast `ArrayList<Object>` to `ArrayList<Message>`.

Consider the [`toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

The `toArray()` method creates an array of type `Object[]` which cannot be cast.  In order to create an array with the correct type, you have to tell the `toArray()` method which type to use:

```
(Message[]) messageList.toArray(new Message[messageList.size()]);
```